# Appropriate TTL for CloudFront 403 Error Caching Minimum TTL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Amazon CloudFront and have an odd issue with image uploading from an iOS app. All images are queued on the server and processed by workers, so the actual photo isn't available until a few seconds after upload.

The app, however, can immediately try to access the photo, getting a 403 error upon the first request if the image isn't done uploading.

Because of CloudFront's 300 second TTL on errors, the 403 gets cached until those 300 seconds are up.

What's an appropriate TTL? (Or is this even the right question?)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but I figured I would answer since I was having this same concern recently.

This will depend on what is acceptable in regards to how often a client can request from your origin on HTTP errors. So for example if you set 403 TTL caching to 1 second each time a client hits your site and the TTL has expired the request is then sent to your origin which may produced undesired traffic on your origin which is especially concerning if your origin is like an EC2 instance.

Comment: My origin is S3, so I'm not too concerned about smashing it. But the ttl setting in AWS console is for MINIMUM TTL so I'd assume that means it may still be cached for longer (my experience suggests so)